# C++11 is it possible to force constexpr to be evaluated when it is used as a function parameter?

Tags: c++11, constexpr

Suppose I have such code:

```
constexpr int foo(int a)
{
    return a * 2;
}
constexpr int bar(const char* str)
{
    return strlen(str);
}
int test(int value)
{
    // Do something
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Case 1, evaluated at compile time
    const int value = foo(1);
    test(value);
    // Case 2, evaluated at run-time
    test(foo(1)); 

    // Case 3
    test(bar("Hello"));
}
```

In the case 1 the `foo` would be evaluated at compile time while in case 2 it would be evaluated at run-time. And even in the case 1 I have to keep the `const` keyword.

Is there any way to force the `constexpr` to be evaluated at compile time even it is `not` going to be assigned to a `const`?

There are some alternative ways to wrap the `int` into template but how about the Case 3? The value is `char[]` which has not chance to be used as a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template.

```
template<int N> struct force_constexpr_eval {
    static const int value = N;
};
int main() {
    auto val = force_constexpr_eval<foo(1)>::value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the question updating. How about if the value can not be used as a template parameter such as `char[]`?